# Debug command route in Linux

Tags: linux, routes, kernel

I want to debug a command line in Linux.

```
$ route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.3.10
```

With command line above, I want to know how Linux kernel handles it. I am doing project about Routing Table, and I will be demo with this. When run this command, kernel executes what, which function the kernel calls (ie: lookup(), fib_tale_insert()...), and how to show value of command when I debug.

I am trying with "strace" but I can't. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll have to recompile the kernel with debug info enabled, see these pages for further information :

https://serverfault.com/questions/251134/how-to-compile-the-kernel-with-debug-symbols

and

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/CompilingAKernel.html

(In a nutshell, You need CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y on the config.)

You could also find some already-compiled kernels with debug enabled, but this will depend on the distribution you are using.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I am using Ubuntu 10.04, kernel 2.x, I also recompile the kernel, and version kernel present is 3.13. When recompile, I was also choose debug kernel and has CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y as you said. Are you know the tool can work what I need?

Comment: I'd say kdb (kernel debugger), but I don't know precisely how to use it, sorry. However, take a look at the tutorials at kernel.org, you should find anything you need on the topic.